# extra custom rewrite with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i got a page made in wordpress - lets call it example. This will be opened by entering http://domain.com/example/

Then in that page i have assigned it to a custom page. In the custom page i have some $_get functions which rewrites the URL to http://domain.com/example/?thegetname=thenameoftheget

I want to rewrite this URL to http://domain.com/example/thenameoftheget/ but when i tro to do this in .htaccess i always get the main custom page.

What can i do to rewrite the url for my needs / Where do i need to do this?

Code:
Functions.php

```
function add_query_vars($aVars) {
$aVars[] = "ord"; // represents the name of the product category as shown in the URL
return $aVars;
}

// hook add_query_vars function into query_vars
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');

function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
$aNewRules = array('spanske-boejninger/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=spanske-boejninger&ord=$matches[1]');
$aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
return $aRules;
}

// hook add_rewrite_rules function into rewrite_rules_array
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

Custom_page.php:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Spanske Bøjninger
*/
if(isset($wp_query->query_vars['ord'])) {
$spanskord = urldecode($wp_query->query_vars['ord']);
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code of your page and the .htaccess file.

Comment: i have added the code used.

Comment: May be the rewrite rules have not been permanently written.